# Grails Integration Test process not ending

Tags: unit-testing, grails, integration-testing

I am running grails Integration Test cases using command "gradle integrationTest". The test cases run properly but, the process itself doesn't end. This is causing issues in jenkins pipeline where we have to move to next step when the test cases are run.

Am I missing out something here? Should I need to provide any other command to terminate the process?

The below is my code;

````
package test

import grails.gorm.transactions.Rollback
import grails.testing.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.testing.spock.OnceBefore
import io.micronaut.core.type.Argument
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus
import io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClientConfiguration
import io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient
import io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClientConfiguration
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
import java.time.Duration

@SuppressWarnings(['JUnitPublicNonTestMethod', 'JUnitPublicProperty'])
@Integration
@Rollback
class StatusControllerIntSpec extends Specification {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StatusControllerIntSpec)

    @Shared HttpClient client

    @OnceBefore
    void init() {
        String baseUrl = "http://localhost:$serverPort"
        HttpClientConfiguration configuration = new DefaultHttpClientConfiguration()
        configuration.readTimeout = Duration.ofMinutes(1)
        this.client  = HttpClient.create(baseUrl.toURL(), configuration)
    }

    void "Test the index method returns application status"() {
        expect:
        HttpStatus.OK
        when:
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.GET('/api/status')
                                        .header("SM_USER","XXXX")
        HttpResponse<List<Map>> resp = client.toBlocking().exchange(request, Argument.of(List, Map))
        then:
        resp.status == HttpStatus.OK
        resp.body()
        resp.body().get(0).get("data").equalsIgnoreCase("Success")
        log.info(resp.body().get(0).get("data"))
        cleanup:
        this.client.close()
        this.client.stop()
    }

}```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0Sxy.png)
````